# How do I make a (Java)script acquire the URL and execute an if statement based on that (#transclusion, #highlight)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Linking to a specific section (with a specific hashtag/id) inside a html document is easy. Highlighting the target section turned out to be more complicated than I thought. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to do on the surface level is ... enabling a user to click on a link which takes him to a specific section (be it div, p, span) of another html document which is at that point highlighted (change text bg color).

Here's how I went about it. I attempted to write a script that would: 
firstly, get the URL of the document and set it as a variable;
secondly, the script would recognize if the URL (var) has a hashtag at the end, that is, if the user got linked to a specific section of the URL;
thirdly, if that would be the case the script would change the background color of the section in question.

If I made many rookie mistakes, I sincerely apologize. I got the highlight working onload and onclick, but not on the condition that there's a hashtag in the url. This would enable me to delete the highlight by deleting the #xyz from the URL.

Here's the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var highlight = function () {
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url === "http://whatever.com/highlight.html#link") {
        document.getElementById('link').style.background = '#FA5858';    
    } else {
        //do nothing
    };
     window.onload = highlight;
    </script>
```

Here's the whole HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE="html">
<head>
    <title>highlight</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .textmain {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 500;        
    }

    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.inview.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var highlight = function () {
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url === "http://pleasepick.co.nf/highlight.html#link") {
        document.getElementById('link').style.background = '#FA5858';    
    } else {
        //do nothing
    };
     window.onload = highlight;
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="textmain">
    <p>Chinese website Xianghuo.com reported a recent incident involving a Hong Kong resident whose Samsung Galaxy S4 allegedly exploded and caught fire while he was playing “Love Machine,” one of the most popular games for Android.</p>
    <p>After hearing a loud popping sound, Mr. Du threw his smartphone onto the couch, where flames quickly spread and caused substantial damage to the house. He and his wife managed to escape unscathed.</p>
    <p>Another similar case was reported a month before this, in which an 18-year-old Swiss girl suffered third-degree burns on her leg from an exploding Samsung Galaxy S3 placed in her pocket. In 2012, the same case was reported in Dublin, where a man’s Galaxy S3 caught fire on his car’s dashboard.</p>
    <p>Another incident involved Apple, Samsung’s key competitor. Reports state that a Chinese woman died from an electric shock when she answered a call on her iPhone 5 while the phone was charging. Another man reportedly suffered the same fate, only this time it led to a coma.</p>
    <p>For Apple, using official chargers is a must for avoiding damage to the phone, not to mention physical injuries.
    In a number of cases, unofficial third-party products were pointed out as the cause of the smartphone mishaps. As in the case of the Swiss woman, her phone was outfitted with a discounted replacement battery. But in Mr. Du’s case, he claimed to have used all legitimate Samsung products.</p>
    <p>Samsung’s Hong Kong unit is currently investigating the incident.</p>
    <br>
     <p>Chinese website Xianghuo.com reported a recent incident involving a Hong Kong resident whose Samsung Galaxy S4 allegedly exploded and caught fire while he was playing “Love Machine,” one of the most popular games for Android.</p>
    <p>After hearing a loud popping sound, Mr. Du threw his smartphone onto the couch, where flames quickly spread and caused substantial damage to the house. He and his wife managed to escape unscathed.</p>
    <p>Another similar case was reported a month before this, in which an 18-year-old Swiss girl suffered third-degree burns on her leg from an exploding Samsung Galaxy S3 placed in her pocket. In 2012, the same case was reported in Dublin, where a man’s Galaxy S3 caught fire on his car’s dashboard.</p>
    <p id="link">Another incident involved Apple, Samsung’s key competitor. Reports state that a Chinese woman died from an electric shock when she answered a call on her iPhone 5 while the phone was charging. Another man reportedly suffered the same fate, only this time it led to a coma.</p>
    <p>For Apple, using official chargers is a must for avoiding damage to the phone, not to mention physical injuries.
    In a number of cases, unofficial third-party products were pointed out as the cause of the smartphone mishaps. As in the case of the Swiss woman, her phone was outfitted with a discounted replacement battery. But in Mr. Du’s case, he claimed to have used all legitimate Samsung products.</p>
    <p>Samsung’s Hong Kong unit is currently investigating the incident.</p>
    </div>



    </body>
```

Comment: Use [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash) instead of `window.location.href`.

Comment: are you trying to detect the #tag in the url

Comment: yes i am  ..... blablbab (character min)

Answer (score 0):

If to detect #tag in url try this.

```
var highlight = function () {
        var url = window.location.href,
        HashTag=/#/g,
        checkHashTag=url.test(HashTag);
        if (checkHashTag) {
        document.getElementById('link').style.background = '#FA5858';    
    } else {
        //do nothing
    };
     window.onload = highlight;
```

Comment: Well... there's `window.location.hash`, so testing `window.location.hash.length > 0` is probably less complicated.

Comment: if you are using window.location.hash you will pick not only the # but also whatever that attch to it for example , http://pleasepick.co.nf/highlight.html#link , using the window.location.hash you will pick #link not only #. in Treakec case it seem to me that he only need to pick any url with or include or has hastag '#'

Comment: i tried both. it didn't work. i suppose window.location.hash is the way to go though, since i could later link to multiple tags/highlights in a document.

Comment: fixed it - had to put onload = "highlight()" inside the body tag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try :

```
if (url.match(/#link/) == "#link") {
    document.getElementById('link').style.background = '#FA5858';    
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

and remove ";" after else{ //do nothing} statement :-)